# Nodejs mysql parse error - не весь запрос передается в mySQL

Tags: node.js, mysql

Небольшой запрос отрабатывает нормально. Большой запрос передается на сторону mySQL не полностью. Передаются только первые ~90 символов.

подскажите куда копать...

код примерно такой:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    database : 'db1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : ''
})

pool.query(getQueryText(id))
```

Возвращается ошибка

```
{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
 that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
        delays SELECT TO_DAYS(time) day, SUM(delay) delay
 FR' at line 3]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
```

Запрос

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
        current_stat
 SELECT time, delay, point
 FROM stat
 WHERE USER = 5 AND challenge = 1
 ;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
        delays SELECT TO_DAYS(time) day, SUM(delay) delay
 FROM current_stat
 WHERE delay < 180000
 GROUP BY day
 ;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
        points SELECT TO_DAYS(time) day, SUM(point) point
 FROM current_stat
 GROUP BY day
;
 SELECT points.day, 60000*points.point / delays.delay point
 FROM delays, points
 WHERE
        delays.day = points.day;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE current_stat;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE delays;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE points;
```

Всё оказалось банально - нельзя использовать в запросе ";". Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @Alien_job, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Это не помогло

Comment: @Alien_job, mysql в сообщении об ошибке как правило выводит кусок запроса, который следует **за** ошибкой. Приведите полный запрос.

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
        current_stat
 SELECT time, delay, point
 FROM stat
 WHERE USER = 5 AND challenge = 1
 ;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
        delays SELECT TO_DAYS(time) day, SUM(delay) delay
 FROM current_stat
 WHERE delay < 180000
 GROUP BY day
 ;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
        points SELECT TO_DAYS(time) day, SUM(point) point
 FROM current_stat
 GROUP BY day
;
 SELECT points.day, 60000*points.point / delays.delay point
 FROM delays, points
 WHERE
        delays.day = points.day;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE current_stat;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE delays;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE points;